# Is Serialized Roaring Bitmaps compressed?

Tags: go, bitset

According to the definition, [roaring bitmap](https://roaringbitmap.org/) is a "better compressed bitset".  Which means it is compressed by nature. But, according to my test, the size of Dgraph's Serialized Roaring Bitmap is not compressed?

```
func main() {
    //github.com/dgraph-io/sroar
    sr := sroar.NewBitmap()
    for {
        if sr.GetCardinality() > 999 {
            break
        }
        sr.Set(uint64(rand.Int()))
    }
    buf := sr.ToBuffer()
    fmt.Printf("sroar size: %d\n", len(buf))
    
    //github.com/RoaringBitmap/roaring
    r := roaring.New()
    for {
        if r.GetCardinality() > 999 {
            break
        }
        r.AddInt(rand.Int())
    }
    var bs bytes.Buffer
    r.WriteTo(&bs)
    fmt.Printf("roar size: %d\n", bs.Len())
}
```

output:

```
sroar size: 152704
roar size: 9936
```

i.e. the "original" roaring bitmap requires 9936 bytes for one thousand `uint32` (that library will cast `int` to `uint32`)  which is 4000 bytes of "raw data", while the Dgraph SRB will require 152704 bytes for one thousand of `uint64` which is 8000 bytes of "raw data".

Is it true that a Roaring Bitmap is by nature compressed, and can be used as-is (without decompress etc)?

Comment: The the size of a roaring bitmap depends on the largest number stored in them. Since you are using random numbers your example probably just show which of the both has the highest number in them.

Comment: ok, that makes sense. However, I tried to use gzip to compress the sroar output, it is very compressible, about only 10% size after compression!  So, entropy-wise, (serialized) roaring bitmap is still not "dense"?